# How to use the GET-method to get the id of the href that is clicked

Tags: php, href, getmethod

I would like to know how I can use the GET-method in my .php file: forumdocument.php to get the ID of the href that is clicked in table.php
I hope this is the right way to begin it:

```
'<a class="formtitellink" href="forumdocument.php" id="$row['ID']">' . $row['Titel'] . '</a>' . "</td>";
```

table.php:

```
$query = "Select *
        from forum";
$resultaat = mysql_query($query, $connectie);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Tijd</th>
<th>Gebruikersnaam</th>
<th>Titel</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat))
  {
  $_SESSION['row'] = $row;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Tijd'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Gebruikersnaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . '<a class="formtitellink" href="forumdocument.php" id="$row['ID']">' . $row['Titel'] . '</a>' . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `echo "<td><a class=\"formtitellink\" href=\"forumdocument.php\" id=\"" . $row['ID'] . "\">" . $row['Titel'] . "</a></td>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GET method is used for name value pairs in a url.

Example: `www.test.com?var1=var1&var2=var2`

Here if we use `$_GET['var1']` the expected value would be `var1`.

Just change your links to reflect the desired variable

```
href="forumdocument.php?rowid=".$row['ID']."
```

Then you can use retrieve the `id` using something like this on `forumdocument.php`

```
$rowid = $_GET['rowid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part

```
a class="formtitellink" href="forumdocument.php" id="$row['ID']"    

a class="formtitellink" href="forumdocument.php"?id="'.$row['ID'].'"
```